# iphone image detail (selected from photo library)

Tags: iphone, ios, image, path, uiimagepickercontroller

i want to Get all detail of image which i have select from iphone library 
like

1. Image name
2. image path
3. Image type
4. image size
5. image ID

I have select image like

```
   picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker1.delegate = self;
    picker1.allowsEditing= YES;
    //picker1.showsCameraControls = YES;
    picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker1 animated:YES];
    [picker1 release];
```

and then for selected image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
{
    isImage = TRUE;

    image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    sendimageview.image=image;
    appDelegate.mediabuttonpress=TRUE;
}
```

and for path i have try this but not getting proper path

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *strPath= [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 strPath = [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
 NSLog(@"*******Path %@",strPath);
```

Need Help ...

Reply

Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use ALAsset class, because I'm not sure, UIImage provides all information you need (esp. GPS-information).

Comment: Not really an answer, you should have added it as a comment.

Comment: @rckoenes Be a little more friendly to the newbie. iPhoneNerd: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you're right, ALAsset should provide more info (but not true path info), but as rckoenes mentioned, this isn't really sufficient as an answer. Put it as a comment and delete the answer, please.

Comment: @fzwo  thanks ..but m really not getting what is Exactly  ALAsset is .. can u provide me any example for this .. ??

Comment: @Vivek2012 it wasn't my suggestion, it was iPhoneNerd's. ALAsset is a kind of proxy object that represents an image or video from the library. It's all explained in the documentation. But I think it might not help you very much, because there are certain things you will never get access to, for instance the path. I think you should read up on ALAssetsLibrary (the photo library in iOS), and decide what you want to do, what you need to get there, and how to get what you need. You will not get the path, and I don't think you'll need it.

Comment: @fzwo do u know any alternative way for that .. my main target is to get image path , size , name and type .. Will u plz help me in this ??

Comment: @Vivek2012 I've said it two times already, and this'll be the last time: You can not get the path of an image from the Library. There is no way. It is impossible. It cannot be done. I can't help you, and nobody else can, either. And even if you could get the path (which you can't), you would not get access (which is moot, because you cannot get the path). And there is no reason to even *want* to get the path. But even if you had a reason, you couldn't. Because it's not possible. To sum it up: **THERE IS NO WAY TO GET THE PATH OF AN IMAGE FROM THE IOS PHOTO LIBRARY.** Please don't ask me again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the "true" path of an image from the library, nor would you have access even if you could get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];

  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

  [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
   ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
   metadataDict = [[representation metadata] retain]; 
   NSLog(@"%@",metadataDict);


  } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
  }];
[library release];
}
```

you have have to declare it with the __block identifier as well.

```
       __block NSDictionary *metaDataDict;
```